# Copy from cell to textbox and maintain all formatting with vba

Tags: excel

I need to be able to copy all data entered in a cell and copy it to a textbox. The text is a mixture of different font styles, including colours, bold, italic, and underlined text.

The user will then be able to enter more information onto the textbox, using different styles etc.

The hope from there is to be able to use vba to copy back to the original cell from the textbox.

The rationale is to allow the user to be able to type quite lengthy notes without the constraints of a cell. I am open to thinking of an embedded object (word). But I could not figure how to do this either.

I found this code which helped posted by David, but it does not include code relating to font colour for example. When I try to add it it throws and error.

Here is the code I found:

```
Sub passCharToTextbox()

'select Textbox 1:
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Textbox 1")).Select

'set text:
Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ActiveCell.Value

'loop through characters in original cell:
For i = 1 To Len(ActiveCell.Value)

    'add bold/italic to the new character if necessary:
    If ActiveCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True Then
        Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True
    Else
        Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = False
    End If
    If ActiveCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic = True Then
        Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic = True
    Else
        Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic = False
    End If

Next i
```

End Sub

If anyone can help I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you need:

- For it to work, make sure you select the correct activeCell and the "textbox 1" exist
- Here are some other options: [TextboxUnderline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msotextunderlinetype)
- Call CopyCelltoTextbox to run macro!

[image]
.

```
Sub passCharToTextbox()
   CopycellFormat ActiveCell
End Sub
Private Sub CopycellFormat(cell As Range)
If Trim(cell(1, 1).Value) = vbNullString Then MsgBox ("select only cell / not emptycell"): Exit Sub
Dim textrange As TextRange2, tbox1 As Shape, fontType As Font2
    With ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next: Err.Clear 'check if Textbox 2 exist
    Set tbox1 = .Shapes("Textbox 2"): Set textrange = tbox1.TextFrame2.textrange
    textrange.Characters.Text = cell.Value
    If Err.Number > 0 Then MsgBox ("Not found Textbox 2")

    For i = 1 To Len(cell.Value)
        Set fontType = textrange.Characters(i, 1).Font
        With cell.Characters(i, 1)
            fontType.Bold = IIf(.Font.Bold, True, 0)                    'add bold/
            fontType.Italic = IIf(.Font.Italic, True, 0)                'add italic/
            fontType.UnderlineStyle = IIf(.Font.Underline > 0, msoUnderlineSingleLine, msoNoUnderline) 'add underline/
        textrange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = .Font.Color 'add Font color
        End With
    Next i


    tbox1.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = cell.Interior.Color 'add background color
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The Gridlock, this looks great. Please allow me a moment to put it into my workbook to try out and I'll post back. Thank you so much for taking the time to help. :)

Comment: Hi The Gridlock, sorry for such a question but I am getting the "select only cell / not empty cell" message although I am choosing an active cell with text in it. I have the entire code in a module and 'textbox1' in sheet one. I have assigned 'Sub CopyCelltoTextbox'.

Comment: I fixed it a bit, please try again!

Comment: The Gridlock, thank you and sorry for appearing such a doughnut. I'm a bit of a novice and get by 'cobbling' code together normally. Can I put all the code in module1 (including the private sub as I have been doing and use my button to call Sub CopyCelltoTextbox() ? :)

Comment: Its close...!!! Its seeing the textbox now, and the cell. Its picking up the fill colour in the cell but not the text itself, bold italic etc....

Comment: my file @stu: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvwbbF6HL04Vi08HBvJj0CBEM_pA?e=5Y1ejt

Comment: The Gridlock, cheers for that share. I've got it now and I'll check it out. Lot easier for me to see it this way buddy. Thanks.

Comment: Ive had a look@The Gridlock. It works on your pre-made cell 'abcd' blue background. Then when you type anything into another cell, say cell B4, just any old text, choose it as active, and press 'copy format' nothing happens apart form the background colour is removed and 'abcd" remains in the box. Sorry to be a right pain here.

Comment: If you have problems, let's upload your file!

Comment: do you want to copy cell content into the shape?

Comment: Thanks @The Gridlock  https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ak5RADqCjpEWeZKHGP-Ys-GOrDg?e=vY3EMr

Comment: Yes please @The Gridlock. Whichever active cell is chosen all the text formatting colours and so on are copied into the shape, overwriting previous in the shape.

Comment: code update! @stu, let copy above code to module and try.