# VBA textbox copy font style

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code

```
Dim TB As TextBox
Dim mycell As Range
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Print").Activate
Cells(r, 1).Select
Dim mytext As String
Set mycell = ActiveCell
With mycell
    Set TB = .Parent.TextBoxes.Add(top:=.top, Left:=.Left, Width:=Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 9)).Width, Height:=42)
    TB.Name = "TB"
    TB.Font.Size = 10
    TB.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
End With
TB.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
For Each c In table.Rows
    If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
        i = i + 1
        If i < [Circumstances_Count] Then
            TB.text = mytext & Chr(149) & " " & c.Value & vbNewLine
        Else
            TB.text = mytext & Chr(149) & " " & c.Value
        End If
        mytext = TB.text
    End If
Next c
```

It works as intended in creating a textbox with bullet points and only containing the fields with data from the range 'table'

The problem is it does not have the formatting of the text such as bold words or italics.

How do i have it mimic the formatting as well?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the same formatting for the whole textbox or you want it to vary depending on each cells?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following code or [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60827598/copy-from-cell-to-textbox-and-maintain-all-formatting-with-vba/60828565#60828565) for more formats:

```
With mycell
    Set TB = .Parent.TextBoxes.Add(Top:=.Top, Left:=.Left, Width:=Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 9)).Width, Height:=42)
    TB.Name = "TB"
    TB.Font.Size = 10
    TB.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    TB.Characters.Text = "test"
    TB.Characters.Font.Bold = True
    TB.Characters.Font.Italic = True
End With
```

Also I notice that you will get an error on the line
`Cells (r, 1) .Select`.

you haven't assigned a value to `r` yet, you probably realize this and know how to fix it.

Comment: Hi Dang, my variable r is defined earlier on in the code :). I know how to set the overall text within the textbox as bold or italic. what i mean is. if c(1).value is  "Hello" and its all in bold. and c(2).value is "Goodbye" in italics, c(3).value is "Hello and Goodbye" in a mixture of Bold and italics. is it possible to preserve that formatting when it is moved into the text box the way it would be if the values were copied and pasted.

Comment: Hi, I have no problem copying and pasting manually. it retains its format. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Hi Dang, i am aware copy and pasting retains its format. i am not trying to copy and paste as thats a manual task. i have a series of fields that a user may or may not enter data with various formatting. i have a textbox that i would like the data copied into. if there is data in the field i need a bullet point added to the textbox and then the data added after it retaining its formatting. does that make a little more sense?

Comment: Hi, Not sure but it looks like you will have to format each character. you just need to ignore your first bullet character formatting for each line in textbox, then
You will have to read and get formatting from each cell `(using cell.Characters (i, 1) and textrange.Characters (i, 1)` ... at the same time as in the link.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to save the position inside the textbox where you have content that came from a bold/italic cell. Then with the length of those cells, you could apply the formatting to the characters inside your textbox after you are done writing to it.

I would suggest using 2 arrays to store the information on the postition and the length of the text that needs to be formatted.

For example, you could try this:

```
Dim BoldList() As Variant
ReDim BoldList(1 To Table.Rows.Count, 1 To 2)

Dim ItalicList() As Variant
ReDim ItalicList(1 To Table.Rows.Count, 1 To 2)

Dim c As Range
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
For Each c In Table.Rows
    If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
        i = i + 1
        
        If c.Font.Bold Then
            BoldList(i, 1) = Len(mytext) + 3
            BoldList(i, 2) = Len(c.Value)
        End If
        
        If c.Font.Italic Then
            ItalicList(i, 1) = Len(mytext) + 3
            ItalicList(i, 2) = Len(c.Value)
        End If
        
        If i < [Circumstances_Count] Then
            TB.Text = mytext & chr(149) & " " & c.Value & vbNewLine
            BoldList(i, 2) = BoldList(i, 2) + 1
            ItalicList(i, 2) = ItalicList(i, 2) + 1
        Else
            TB.Text = mytext & chr(149) & " " & c.Value
        End If
        mytext = TB.Text
    End If
Next c

'Apply the formatting
For i = 1 To UBound(BoldList)
    If Not IsEmpty(BoldList(i, 1)) Then
        TB.Characters(BoldList(i, 1), BoldList(i, 2)).Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To UBound(ItalicList)
    If Not IsEmpty(ItalicList(i, 1)) Then
        TB.Characters(ItalicList(i, 1), ItalicList(i, 2)).Font.Italic = True
    End If
Next i
```